# Don't display items that are out of stock

Tags: sql, join, count, stock

Its a  Lending Library where products which are currently out on loan on a particular date are displayed, if the product quantity is greater than the Lend total display it, if not display nothing (show no records) If the SUM/Count = 0 again dont display it.

I have 2 tables Lending & Products, when an item is loaned out a record is added to the Lending table containing Product_ID, Date on loan.  The product table has the current Product Stock level called Product_QTY

Heres my attempt:

```
SELECT dbo.Products.Product_QTY - COUNT(dbo.Lending.Lend_ID) as Lend_Total
FROM (dbo.Lending INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON dbo.Lending.Product_ID = dbo.Products.Product_ID)
WHERE dbo.Lending.Product_ID = 18 AND Dates = '11/09/2022'
GROUP BY dbo.Lending.Product_ID, dbo.Products.Product_QTY, Lend_Total
HAVING Lend_Total < 1
```

The issue is that even if the stock level is zero it still display's the record show zero as the stock level

Lending Table:
Lend_ID
Product_ID
Date

Products Table:
Product_ID
Product_QTY

I have been stuck on this problem for a few weeks now, gratful for any help please, thank you.

[Lending Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH4vS.png)

[Products Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmo9A.png)

Comment: I don't see any condition that would exclude the rows with stock level zero. What column refers to "Stock level"?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? I'd expect an error for the above query.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Stock Levels are Products_QTY as in Quantity

Comment: The Query works, it displays a row show zero stock, I dont want any rows showing if the stock levels are below 1.  I'm using MSSQL.  I have this query working on a calendar style sheets show available to lend, not available.

Comment: when run it shows Lend_Total as 0

Comment: Please update your question to show sample data for both tables and the result you want to see based on that data. Your sample data should cover the use cases where there is stock level > 0 and where there isn't stock level > 0

Comment: Lending Table: Lend_ID int, Lend_Count int ((1)), Product_ID int

Comment: Products Table: Product_ID int, Product_QTY int

Comment: Product Table: Product_ID = 18, Product_QTY 10. and Lending Table: Product_ID = 18, Lend_Count = 1, Dates = 11/09/2022

Comment: Update your question, so that all relevant information is in one place. Don’t provide additional information in comments